# How to implement multiple horizontal lists inside a column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement multiple horizontal lists that contain cards with some details, and now all i get is just white screens(without errors)

This is my code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('fsfssffs'),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('fsfssffs'),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
);
```

I want to achieve something like the facebook stories

Comment: Here is better example you can check this https://github.com/zmqgithub/styled_list

Comment: you are missing 'return' keyword before Card into itemBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not returning any widget from your `itemBuilder` method which is why you were unable to see anything on screen.

---

Basically, there are 2 solutions for this, I am giving you idea using a `build()` method you can do it in your `itemBuilder`.

(1) Use `=>` (fat arrow notation)

Example:

```
Widget build(context) => Text("Hi");
```

(2) Use `return`.

```
Widget build(context) {
  return Text("Hi");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `=>` on List itemBuilder to return the items:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('fsfssffs'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            Card(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('fsfssffs'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```